# Adicionar todas as últimas mudanças ao commit no git

Tags: git

Sempre quando eu faço várias mudanças em arquivos no Git, eu saio adicionando as mudanças uma-a-uma por meio do `git add`. É um processo um pouco chato, gostaria de saber se tem um comando pra adicionar todas as mudanças "not staged" de uma vez só.

Comment: Voce ja pensou que existe um motivo para que tenha que adicionar todos arquivos manualmente?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normalmente uso o comando:

```
git add .
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: A partir da versão 2.0 do Git o comando `git add .` equivale a `git add -A`. Nas versões 1.x, `git add -A` adiciona automaticamente todas as alterações (novos arquivos, modificados e deletados) enquanto `git add .` adiciona no stage apenas novos arquivos/modificados.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode adicionar vários arquivos no `git` através do prompt interativo `git add -i`

No prompt interativo você tem duas opções que são mais usadas normalmente que são:

- `update` (`2` ou `u`): para você escolher quais arquivos já adicionados anteriormente, você quer adicionar no stage.
- `add untracked` (`4` ou `a`) para você adicionar arquivos ainda não incluidos ao versionamento do git.

Selecionando uma das opções acima, o modo interativo vai abrir pra você mais ou menos assim:

```
      staged           unstaged path
1:    unchanged        +1/-1 folder/arquivo1.txt
2:    unchanged        +1/-1 folder/arquivo2.txt
3:    unchanged        +1/-1 folder/arquivo3.txt
4:    unchanged        +1/-1 folder/arquivo4.txt
5:    unchanged        +1/-1 folder/arquivo5.txt
6:    unchanged        +1/-1 folder/arquivo6.txt
7:    unchanged        +1/-1 folder/arquivo7.txt
```

Você tem várias formas de adicionar esses arquivos que estão listados acima no stage.

- Para adicionar um a um, digite o número do arquivo.
- Para adicionar um range, digite n-m (exemplo: `2-4` adiciona os arquivos 2, 3, 4 e 5 de uma vez)
- Para adicionar todos, digite `*`
- Para remover um arquivo ou um range, digite `-` antes do número ou range.

Você pode executar varios comandos no mesmo prompt também, exemplos:

```
# Adiciona ao stage todos arquivos, menos os numeros 4, 5 e 6
Update>> * -4-6 

# Adiciona ao stage todos arquivos menos o 5
Update>> 1-3 4 6-7
```

O comando `git add - A` funciona mas ele não é recomendado, porque ele adiciona de forma forçada, todos arquivos que não foram versionados, isso nem sempre é bom porque as vezes você quer fazer commits de forma separada para contextualizar melhor seu progresso e também você pode acabar adicionando algum arquivo indesejado que não estava no `.gitignore` antes.

### UPDATE

Só mais dois comandos para adicionar mudanças que são muito úteis e são mais usados com frequência.

- `git add -u`: adiciona todos arquivos modificados ao stage, apenas os arquivos que já foram adicionados ao git serão adicionados.
- `git add -p`: Adiciona pedaços de código que foram modificados, também funciona apenas com arquivos já adicionados ao git e é o mais recomendado de ser usado, pois você consegue contextualizar melhor o que você está atualizando.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: boa resposta, nunca tentei usar o git interativamente ...

Answer (score 7):

Você pode utilizar:

```
git add -A
```

Answer (score 5):

Usando:

```
git add -A
```

e

```
git add --all
```

você obtêm o mesmo resultado (na verdade o primeiro e uma abreviação do segundo).

Outra maneira seria usar *er*:

```
git add *
```

Mas para isso funcionar você precisa estar no repositório raiz fazendo com que todos arquivos sejam pegos pela *er*.

Em uma caso extremo se você quiser deixar esses comandos ainda mais abreviados, pode tentar [git aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) para abrevia-los.

Answer (score 4):

Se são arquivos **NOVOS**, não tem como escapar do `git add -A` ou `git add .`, porém, se há alterações em arquivos **EXISTENTES**:

```
git commit -am "Sua Mensagem"
```

Já adiciona e dá uma mensagem ao teu branch