# Adicionando meus arquivos no GitHub

Tags: git, github

Quando iniciei meu projeto, coloquei todos os meus no GitHub corretamente, mas com as modificações que fui fazendo esqueci de ir atualizando os arquivos no git.

Agora eu necessito passar todos os arquivos para o GitHub, como estou iniciando no git não tenho ideia como atualizá-los

Comment: Queres fazer via consola ou tens algum programa para gerir o git?

Comment: Seria bom você explicar melhor o quer fazer e como quer fazer. Se você não estava atualizando o repo, é porque não tem nada importante lá neste momento, certo? Não seria melhor simplesmente criar um novo repositório e upar todos os arquivos para ele?

Comment: Fiz um [post bem interessante sobre o git](http://www.linuxpro.com.br/2017/04/git-simples-e-rapido/) no meu [Blog](http://www.linuxpro.com.br).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiramente se você tem o *Git* instalado, via linha de comandos você precisa abrir o *Git Bash* navegar até o diretório do seu repositório local:

```
cd c:/seuCaminhoDoRepositorio
```

Depois você opcionalmente pode verificar o status do seu repositório:

```
git status
```

Para adicionar todos os arquivos que você deseja commitar no stage:

```
git add .
```

Feito isso execute o comando abaixo para fazer o commit com uma mensagem:

```
git commit -m "Sua mensagem"
```

Por fim execute o comando push para enviar suas alterações

```
git push
```

ou

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: `git add .` não vai adicionar os arquivos novos. Ou vai?

Comment: `git add .` adiciona os arquivos no cabeçalho do seu git local. Depois de ter adicionado no seu git local, pra mandar pro git remoto, você precisar dar um `git commit -m "Descrição das alterações"` e depois um `git push origin master`.

Comment: @LINQ Sim (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142726/adicionar-todas-as-%C3%BAltimas-mudan%C3%A7as-ao-commit-no-git/142763#142763)

Comment: então é só dar os comandos acima ?

Comment: @luismatheus Sim, pode executar os comandos da resposta.

Comment: @Renan Acabei de fazer um teste e não adiciona com os deletados apenas. Vide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/572660/4190610

Comment: aparentemente esta enviando os arquivos

Comment: Funcionou, os arquivos foram enviados, mas o estranho é que minha pasta Bower_components não foi enviada

Comment: Essa sua pasta Bower_components tinha arquivos?

Comment: sim estão todos meus plugins bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

[Git](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) é uma ferramenta de controle de versão criada por Linus Torvalds para auxilio na criação do kernel Linux. A ferramenta possui sua própria cultura, termos específicos de linguajar e conceitos. É recomendado bastante pesquisa para produtividade nas suas aplicações. No entanto é bastante comum que desenvolvedores precisem usar a ferramenta, antes mesmo de dominar todos os conceitos (commit, diff, pull request, status, etc.). Para estes casos, é recomendável um roteiro mínimo para uso da ferramenta de modo cego, sem prejudicar o aprendizado. Não é pretenção deste post 'dar uma aula' de git, uma vez que temas abrangentes não estão de acordos com a filosofia desta comunidade. Segue recomendação de um modelo cego de roteiro para iniciantes em git:

**1 - Clone seu repositório (git clone) -** Com o comando `git clone www.seurepositorio.com` você terá acesso a todo seu projeto, incluindo arquivos de dados que enviarão informações novas para o repositório original. Faça as alterações nesse repositório (editando arquivos, arrastando pastas, etc).

**2 - Sugira adição de novos arquivos (git add) -** A ferramenta git supõe que sua aplicação está sendo construída por múltiplos desenvolvedores (para qual ela foi criada), ainda que seja muito útil para desenvolvimento solo. Com o comando `git add *` você sugere adição dos novos arquivos no projeto. Você também pode optar também por `git add nomeDoArquivo.Ext` para adição de um arquivo específico.

**3 - Faça um commit (git commit) -** Depois de todas as alterações feitas, é hora de `commitar` seu projeto. É o ato de enviar uma proposta com todas as modificações aos administradores **LOCAIS** (na sua própria rede ou máquina) do projeto (no seu caso, você mesmo). Use o comando `git commit -m "Anote aqui as alterações como histórico"`.

**4 - Envie seu projeto (git push) -** Depois de todas as alterações feitas no repositório local, é hora de dar um `push` seu projeto. É o ato de enviar uma proposta com todas as modificações aos administradores **REMOTO** (o repositório original) do projeto (no seu caso, você mesmo). Use o comando `git push origin"`.

**Conclusão: -**  Git é uma ferramenta poderosa, com diversos comandos que fazem parte da rotina de controle de versão. Para o caso específico deste tópico, é recomendado se familiarizar com essas quatro etapas. Ainda que exista outros comandos como `git push` (atualiza o repositório) e `git status` (atual situação de arquivos vigiados), não é recomendado para o iniciante que ainda trabalha com desenvolvimentos solos, interromper seus projetos para se aprofundar no git. A necessidade de aprender novos comandos do git virá com naturalidade. Embora tenha uma grande quantidade de textos na internet sobre a ferramenta, dificilmente achará um com qualidade didática. Posso citar apenas dois razoáveis como o [tableless](https://tableless.com.br/iniciando-no-git-parte-2/) e o guia [prático do git](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html) feito por Roger Dudler .

Answer (score 2):

Acho excelente aprender os comandos básicos pelo menos de *GIT*, afinal mesmo quem usa algum cliente git com interface gráfica uma hora vai precisar de algum comando, ainda sim como um adicional as demais respostas gostaria de lhe indicar algumas ferramentas que tem como intuito facilitar o uso do *Git*, um exemplo é o [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com) que é tem versões para *Windows* e *Mac*

[image: github desktop]

Outra maneira de gerenciar teus arquivos é usando a interface web, você pode fazer o upload:

[image: upload]

Ou simplesmente arrastar uma pasta inteira:

[image: drag drop]

### Alternativas

Fora o *Github Desktop* e a interface Web também existem programas como:

- [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) que suporta não só o Bitbucket, mas qualquer repositório Git e tem versões para *Windows* e *Mac*
- [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com) tem versões para *Windows*, *Mac* e *Linux*

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você tem que colocar seus arquivos novos no header do seu git local com o seguinte comando:

`git add .`

Em seguida você tem que criar uma versão descrevendo as novas alterações:
`git commit -m "Descreva as alterações nesse limite de aspas"`
Feito isso, já pode mandar sua versão para seu git remoto com o seguinte comando:
`git push origin master`

Comment: Isso mesmo @Ikaro Pinheiro, porém eu já respondi anteriormente dando mais detalhes, foi quase um ctrl+c e ctrl+v a sua reposta rs